# Bar Notation Problem

Tags: fractions

everyone! I came across a problem in math that dealt with bar notation. Does anyone know how, for instance, 1.234(with a bar notation over the 34) is expressed as a fraction? I know already how 1.22(with a bar notation over the 22) is expressed as 1 and 2/9. Any answer would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Let $x=1.2\overline{34}$. Then $100x=123.4\overline{34}$. Subtracting the former from the latter gives you
$$100x-x=123.4-1.2=122.2$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hint: Multiply $1.2\overline{34}$ with 100

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, "with a bar notation over the 34"

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes there is no automatic update on comments:)

Comment: @lab: sorry about the hassle here. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $x=1.2\overline{34}$

$\implies 100x=123.4\overline{34}$

So, $100x-x=123.4\overline{34}-1.2\overline{34}=122.2$

---

Alternatively, $1.2\overline{34}=1.2+0.01\cdot 0.\overline{34}$

Now, let $S=0.\overline{34}=0.343434\cdots$

$100S=34.3434\cdots$

$\implies 100S-S=34.3434\cdots-0.343434\cdots=34$

$\implies 1.2\overline{34}=1.2+0.01\cdot\frac{34}{99}$

Comment: OK, thank you guys so much for your help! I get it now.

Comment: @user2516595, my pleasure. If there are $n$ digits inside the bar, we need to multiply by $10^n$  where integer $n\ge1$

Comment: wait so the answer cant be 122.2 though can it?

Comment: or would it be 122.2/99

Comment: yup never mind got confsed. i get it

Comment: @user2516595, we have $99x=\frac{1222}{10}=\frac{611}5,x=\frac{611}{5\cdot99}$

Comment: This is safely a comment already. And talk about volume?

Comment: @amWhy, you have probably missed the alternative method

Answer (score 1):

$1.2\overline{34}= 1\frac{2\frac{34}{99}}{10}=1\frac{232}{990}=1\frac{116}{495}$

Answer (score -1):

let x=1.23434..... eq.1

so eq.1 mulyiply by 10

10x = 12.3434... eq.2

so eq.2 multiply by 100

1000x =1234.34..... eq.3

subtract eq.2 from eq.3

1000x-10x = 1234.34-12.34

990x =1222

x=1222/990=611/495